# How to gracefully restart NodeJS server on an uncaught exception?

Tags: node.js, azure, iis, express

I'm using [the express-domain-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-domain-middleware) module to wrap my requests in a domain. In my error middleware, I have the following check:

```
if(err.domain) {
 //something should happen here, it's completely uncaught
}
else {
 //silly kids, I'll log this and send a 500;
```

The above code snippet is based on this example from the `express-domain-middleware` documentation:

```
//with domain-middleware
app.use(require('express-domain-middleware'));
app.use(app.router);

app.use(function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
 console.log('error on request %d %s %s', process.domain.id, req.method, req.url);
 console.log(err.stack);
 res.send(500, "Something bad happened. :(");

 if(err.domain) {
  //you should think about gracefully stopping & respawning your server
  //since an unhandled error might put your application into an unknown state
 }
});

app.get('/error', function(req, res, next) {
 db.query('SELECT happiness()', process.domain.intercept(function(rows) {
  fs.readFile('asldkfjasdf', process.domain.intercept(function(contents) {
    process.nextTick(process.domain.intercept(function() {
      throw new Error("The individual request will be passed to the express error handler, and your application will keep running.");
   }));
  }));
 }));
});
```

What I don't want to do if this exception occurred outside of a domain is call `process.exit(1)` (I don't think anyone would actually do this, right?). I also don't want to leave my application in a dangerous state. I'd rather just log the uncaught exception so I can refactor it later, gracefully restart this domain (server?), and get on about things.

### Assumptions

1. By taking this approach, the larger application will not be compromised by the instability of one domain. I can restart without terminating any other connections. (**Edit**: I created a route that would throw an unhandled exception on purpose and logged into the application in a separate tab. By forcing the exception and Forever restart, I also killed the 'legit' session-- I'm guessing I did something wrong).
2. The user won't know what happened if I just restart the server. I assume they'll just end up seeing the login screen once they refresh without any knowledge as to why. If this was a handled exception, I would send a JSON response to the client explaining what happened or redirect the user to an error page. What is the correct way to handle this scenario when the exception is unhandled?

### TLDR;

- This application is running in Azure on IIS. What command(s) do I send so the application restarts gracefully? I'm unfamiliar as to what behavior IIS will take vs `Forever`. I purposefully started the app locally using `Forever` and observed it restarted automagically when forcing an unhandled exception-- but I develop on a Mac and the application runs on Windows. Need a Windows solution =)

**Edit Edit**: *Please* correct me if there's misconceptions I'm harboring about what happens inside of a domain and uncaught exceptions. I'm here to learn!!

Comment: Your server could easily be in a bad state after an uncaught exception so there is no universal way to recover after that other than shutting down the server and then restarting it.  You cannot do that from within the server itself.  Instead, you will need to exit the server when the exception occurs and then use some sort of outside agent to restart it from scratch (like Forever).

Comment: Have a look at [clustering](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) They're basically sub-processes that are identical so if one fails, another spawns and since it's a "fresh" copy, *on its own* it's almost like starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

A node program can restart itself like this with the help of spawn:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

spawn('sh', ['-c', 'sleep 2; node /home/username/Desktop/MainNodeApplication.js'], {
        detached: true,
        stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'ignore']
    });

process.exit(0);
```

The previous code is written to work on a Linux machine with a very simple node script stored at /home/username/Desktop/MainNodeApplication.js.  This code spawns another process, detaches it from the parent process, then immediately exits.   Meanwhile the spawned process restarts the node script in 2 seconds, after we are good and sure the other instance had time to shut down.

This doesn't get you all the way to what you want but it will allow you to gracefully restart your code.  You could pass it arguments when you start it to let it better know what state it should come up in or pass it error information to relay to the user.  You could do this by just adding arguments to the call to node in the spawn arguments.